# Default cell type in Slide Show

Tags: cells, slideshows

For slide show, the default cell style (when it is created) is `Text`.  However, I would like to change that default style to `Input`.  How can I change this?

Comment: Ah, it seems you are using Journal stylesheet or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick fix is to use

```
SetOptions[ EvaluationNotebook[], DefaultNewCellStyle -> "Input"]
```

if you want to restrict changes only to `SlideShow` environment put or edit  your stylesheet with:

```
Cell[StyleData["Notebook","SlideShow"],
   DefaultNewCellStyle->"Section"
]
```

assuming your `StyleDefinitions` are in form of a `_String/FileName` not a `Notebook` you can set `DefaultNewCellStyle` for given environment:

```
SetOptions[
    EvaluationNotebook[],
    StyleDefinitions - >Notebook[{
        Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> CurrentValue[ 
           EvaluationNotebook[],StyleDefinitions]
        ]],
        Cell[StyleData["Notebook","SlideShow"],
           DefaultNewCellStyle->"Section"
        ]
    }]
]
```

Evaluate it in that notebook or replace `EvaluationNotebook[]` with a `_NotebookObject` pointing to your notebook.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working (and it seems to mess up the font styles etc in my current slide show).  The comment that you posted under my question did work.  Why did you delete it?  Please put it back.

Comment: @QuantumDot ok, edited.

Comment: Very nice.  Thanks