# How to make a StyleSheet with a custom-defined Cell type that will be open by default?

Tags: stylesheet, education

I am making a StyleSheet to conveniently use them for homeworks and class works in Mathematics classes. I base it on the JournalArticle StyleSheet. I would like to make it such that by Default opens the Cell with the style "DisplayFormula". Unlike in others, in JournalArticle StyleSheet it is entitled "Equation".

This question is related to [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/114780/default-cell-type-in-slide-show). Following the advice of @Kuba there I tried to introduce the following definition for the "Equation" cell style:

```
Cell[StyleData["Equation"],
 DefaultNewCellStyle->"Equation",
 MenuSortingValue->1440,
 FontFamily->"Times New Roman",
 FontSize->16,
 FontWeight->"Plain",
 FontSlant->"Italic",
 Magnification->1.5]
```

This, however, does not work, and the notebook always open a Text cell by default.

What do I miss?

Comment: If you follow Kuba's answer, you should add `Cell[StyleData["Notebook"], DefaultNewCellStyle->"Equation"]` instead.

Comment: @Carl Woll Where this statement should be placed? In the cell definition for the "Equation"? In the head cell of the Private Style Definitions, may be? The latter has the form: `Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> FrontEnd`FileName[{"Article"}, "JournalArticle.nb", 
  CharacterEncoding -> "UTF-8"]]]`.

Comment: Just add it to the style sheet in the usual way, by typing "Notebook" in the input field of the style sheet, and then editing the new "Notebook" cell.

Comment: @ Carl Woll Thank you. I succeeded. Why would not you write this as a regular answer, so that I would be able to accept it and like this, finalize the question?